How do I link an already imported paragraph field?
I am working on a custom migration in Drupal where nodes have a reference field to paragraphs. The source data is in JSON format, and a sample structure looks like this:
    {
  "sample": [
    {
      "title": "Node Title A",
      "body": "This is the body of Node A.",
      "related_data": {
        "field_title": "Item Suite A",
        "field_description": "Manage and support your items efficiently",
        "field_unique_id": "101"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Node Title B",
      "body": "This is the body of Node B.",
      "related_data": {
        "field_title": "System Management Tool",
        "field_description": "Comprehensive solution for item tracking",
        "field_unique_id": "102"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I have successfully created a migration for paragraphs using the related_data object. Now, I want to create a migration for nodes, but instead of creating new paragraphs every time, I need to link existing paragraphs based on the unique field_unique_id.
My Questions:
How can I link already imported paragraphs to nodes based on a unique identifier?
Is there a specific plugin or approach in Drupal migration to achieve this?
Are there any common pitfalls to avoid when referencing existing entities in migrations?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
